# using auth in laravel service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container

whenever i tried to use `\Auth::User()` i am getting non object property because my `Auth::guest()` returns true whenever i use them in service provider

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use App\relations;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RelationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        \Auth::User()->id;

        $relation_friend_for_logged_user = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users"));

        $value = "asd";

        // for injecting objct
        View()->share('count', $value);
    }
```

but why `\Auth::guest()` is returning true whether i am logged in

Comment: try to put your logic into if statement -- if(Auth::User()){ .. 'your logick'.. }

Comment: I am logged in whenever i tried using this Auth::user in my custom service provider which i registered is shows non object error when i tried to debug the auth::guest() seems to return true which means no user is logged in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) for this. As far as I know the authenticated user is not yet available in your service providers boot method.

```
public function boot(Guard $auth) {
    view()->composer('*', function($view) use ($auth) {
        // get the current user
        $currentUser = $auth->user();

        // do stuff with the current user
        // ...

        // pass the data to the view
        $view->with('currentUser', $currentUser);
    });
}
```

<sub>Code modified from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-get-the-current-authenticated-user-laravel-5</sub>

Comment: I was wondering why this was not working, and want to add that something not too obvious is that for Laravel 5.1 you have to add to the top: **use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;** or it won't work.