# Laravel making a global object with AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I'm trying to make a user object in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider like this:

```
    public function boot()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    view()->share('user',$user);
}
```

And when I'm saying in for example index.blade.php:

```
{!! $user->name !!}
```

It throws the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\resources\views\tickets\index.blade.php)

So obviously the object is empty but why is that? Ofcourse when I tested this I was logged in.

Comment: Try running `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Then please do `dd($user)` in the service provider to see what it actually is...

Comment: Do you mean this:    public function boot()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        view()->share('user',dd($user);
    }

Comment: No. `$user = Auth::user(); dd($user);` everything afterwards doesn't matter, because the execution is stopped.

Comment: I think your not authenticated the user. So `$user` is `null` and you are trying to get a property `name`

Comment: Check this --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201459/using-auth-in-laravel-service-provider#comment52288384_32201459

Comment: @user4621032 thanks that worked for me!