# Auth::user() return null in ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-5

i try to get the user id in ServiceProvider but Auth::user() return null after successfully login where is the problem ?

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
use App\Offer;
use Auth;
class MasterPageProfileServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        dd(Auth::user()); // => null
        $offersTrashed = Offer::onlyTrashed()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        View::share('offersTrashed', $offersTrashed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using auth in laravel service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201459/using-auth-in-laravel-service-provider)

Comment: no in controllers i use the same way . when i remove use auth i get error