# Can't get session variables in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, session, boot, laravel-8

I would like to share some variables from session in all views in Laravel 8. According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) I call `View::share()` method in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {    
        // Variables shared in all views.
        View::share('showModal', session('showModal'));
    }
}
```

The problem is that although the session `showModal` key is really set, I can't get it in `AppServiceProvider::boot()`. If I call `session('showModal')` in the controller on in view I can see the correct value. Only `AppServieProvider` returns `null`.

Can somebody explain please what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using auth in laravel service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201459/using-auth-in-laravel-service-provider)

Comment: Well, I don't see a reason to use `View::share(...)` for a variable that is already in the `$_SESSION`. Variables in the session by **default** are accessible in all views. i.e `{{session("showModal")}}`

Comment: For example if value will change before the call in view?.

Answer (score 1):

Well, alternatively, you could set up a middleware to be responsible for updating your session variable before the call in view.

Below is something I implemented for setting/retrieving the user permissions before the call in view.

#### STEP 1

Generate the middleware: `php artisan make:middleware GetPermissions`

You will find the middleware in `App\Http\Middleware` directory.

#### STEP 2

Add your logic for setting your session variable in the new middleware's `handle` method.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GetPermissions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->session()->put("permissions", optional(auth()->user(), function ($user) {
                return $user->permissions()->pluck("name")->toArray();
            }) ?? []);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### STEP 3

Register your middleware in the `protected $middlewareGroups` array of  `App\Http\Kernel.php` class file.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // ...

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            // ...
            
            \App\Http\Middleware\GetPermissions::class,
        ],
        
    // ...  

}
```

With that setup, every time a request is made, the latest values of your session variable will be set.

You will then have access to latest session variable value in your `helper`files, `controllers` as whereas `views`.

Demo for accessing it in views:

```php
{{session("permissions")}}
```